# QT - voice chat via udp with an intermediary server

Tags: c++, qt

Hi I am trying to communicate two computers via udp with an intermediary server. When I connect them directly there is not much delay. However, when the intermediary server the delays are about one second in local network. Could you please take a look in my code?

SERVER

```
#include "server.h"

server::server(QObject *parent)
    : QObject{parent}
{

}
void server::startServer()
{
    socket = new QUdpSocket();
    socket->bind(1234);
    qDebug() << "listening on port: 1234";
    connect(socket, &QUdpSocket::readyRead, this, &server::socketReadyRead);
}

void server::socketReadyRead()
{
    QByteArray buffer;
    while (socket->hasPendingDatagrams())
    {
        buffer.resize(socket->pendingDatagramSize());
        socket->readDatagram(buffer.data(), buffer.size(), &sender, &senderPort);
        
        if (!hasTwoClients)
        {
            qDebug() << "!hasTwoClients";
            if (clientOne.isNull())
            {
                clientOne = sender;
                clientOnePort = senderPort;
            }
            else if ((clientOne != sender) || (clientOnePort != senderPort))
            {
                clientTwo = sender;
                clientTwoPort = senderPort;
                hasTwoClients = true;
            }
        }
        else if (sender == clientOne)
            socket->writeDatagram(buffer.data(), buffer.size(), clientTwo, clientTwoPort);
        else if (sender == clientTwo)
            socket->writeDatagram(buffer.data(), buffer.size(), clientOne, clientOnePort);
    }
}
```

CLIENT

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}


void MainWindow::on_sendButton_clicked()
{
    socket = new QUdpSocket();
    input = new QAudioInput(setFormat(), this);
    inputDevice = input->start();
    output = new QAudioOutput(setFormat(), this);
    outputDevice = output->start();


    QByteArray buffer;

    while(true)
    {
        if (input->bytesReady() > 5000)
        {
            buffer = inputDevice->read(input->bytesReady());  
            socket->writeDatagram(buffer.data(), buffer.size(), QHostAddress("192.168.0.111"), 1234);
           
            QByteArray buffer;
            buffer.resize(socket->pendingDatagramSize());
            socket->readDatagram(buffer.data(), buffer.size(), &senderHost, &senderPort);
            outputDevice->write(buffer.data(), buffer.size());

        }
    }
}

void MainWindow::socketReadyRead()
{
    QByteArray buffer;
    while(socket->hasPendingDatagrams())
    {
        buffer.resize(socket->pendingDatagramSize());
        socket->readDatagram(buffer.data(), buffer.size());
        outputDevice->write(buffer.data(), buffer.size());
    }
}

QAudioFormat MainWindow::setFormat()
{
    QAudioFormat format;
    format.setSampleRate(16000);
    format.setChannelCount(2);
    format.setSampleSize(32);
    format.setCodec("audio/pcm");
    format.setByteOrder(QAudioFormat::LittleEndian);
    format.setSampleType(QAudioFormat::UnSignedInt);

    return format;
}
```

Is it possible to do it better via udp?